# Why do TypeScript linters want a string for zIndex?

Tags: typescript

For example the following code:

```
element.style.zIndex = 4;
```

returns:

> Type '4' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.

It goes away if I assign '4', but this doesn't feel right.

Comment: It is supposed to be a string. Typescript is correct in this case. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp. In particular the line: `object.style.zIndex = "auto|number|initial|inherit"`. Note that it takes a number, in quotes, aka a string. So your correct code would indeed be `element.style.zIndex = '4'`

Comment: The MDN cites integer (a subset of number):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/integer#Interpolation
from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
Note the formal syntax "auto | <integer>"

Comment: The documentation you cite is correct for specifying the z-index *in a CSS document*, but it doesn't apply to accessing css properties through javascript.

Comment: I agree, but I can't find the corresponding spec on the style object.  Although integers always worked there for as long as I can remember developing on the web.

Comment: Hmm. Heres docs on the `HTMLElement.style` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style, but I didn't see anything in there explicitly saying it should be a string (to your point), and the link to the actual specification is broken. It may work with a number, but I don't know if that's because it can actually uses a number in it's implementation or if javascript is doing some type coercion on it.

Comment: How about `element.style.zIndex = '42 !important';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do TypeScript linters want a string for zIndex?

Cause it is *implicitly* converted to a `string` and its better to be explicit.

## Demo

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing answer thanks.  I had some how missed (forgotten?) the conversion that is always happening!